# SQL PIVOT one column only

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

So I have this "table" which is a result of the query

```
SELECT  Valoare 
FROM GEConfig 
WHERE  Cimp IN('Societate','Adresa','Banca','CapitalSocial','Cont','CUI','NrRegCom','ModulReceptiiExtCotaTVA')
```

GeConfig is a table what is used to configurate the aplication for each client so the data that will result from the query above will be diferent for eaech client.

```
    Valoare
========================
1   aaa
2   bbb
3   ccc
4   ddd
5   eee
6   fff
7   ggg
8   hhh
```

I want to pivot this table so it will look like

```
  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8
   aaa   bbb   ccc   ddd   eee   fff   ggg   hhh
```

I don't have any aggregate, I only have that one Column with 8 rows which I want to make into 1 row with 8 columns.

Why I want this? I have to use into Rave Report.
I tried something like this

```
select Valoare
  , [1] 
  , [2]
  , [3]
from
(
  select   Valoare from GEConfig 
) x
pivot
(
  max(Valoare)
  for Valoare in([1], [2], [3])
)p
```

But it clear that is very very wrong as I have no idea on how to use a PIVOT.

Comment: The number in the table are ID or just line number?

Comment: Line number, I have only that column that is relevant to this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more general approach is to add a row number and use it as anchor

```
WITH _ID AS (
  SELECT Valoare
       , _ID = Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY Valoare)
  FROM   GEConfig
)
SELECT [1] = MAX(CASE WHEN _ID = 1 THEN Valoare ELSE NULL END)
     , [2] = MAX(CASE WHEN _ID = 2 THEN Valoare ELSE NULL END)
     , [3] = MAX(CASE WHEN _ID = 3 THEN Valoare ELSE NULL END)
     , [4] = MAX(CASE WHEN _ID = 4 THEN Valoare ELSE NULL END)
     , [5] = MAX(CASE WHEN _ID = 5 THEN Valoare ELSE NULL END)
     , [6] = MAX(CASE WHEN _ID = 6 THEN Valoare ELSE NULL END)
     , [7] = MAX(CASE WHEN _ID = 7 THEN Valoare ELSE NULL END)
     , [8] = MAX(CASE WHEN _ID = 8 THEN Valoare ELSE NULL END)
FROM   _ID
```

---

**Static case**

You can use a real `PIVOT` as in the answer from MarkD, or you can use a fake one

```
SELECT [1] = MAX(CASE WHEN Valoare = 'aaa' THEN 'aaa' ELSE NULL END)
     , [2] = MAX(CASE WHEN Valoare = 'bbb' THEN 'bbb' ELSE NULL END)
     , [3] = MAX(CASE WHEN Valoare = 'ccc' THEN 'ccc' ELSE NULL END)
     , [4] = MAX(CASE WHEN Valoare = 'ccc' THEN 'ccc' ELSE NULL END)
     , [5] = MAX(CASE WHEN Valoare = 'ddd' THEN 'ddd' ELSE NULL END)
     , [6] = MAX(CASE WHEN Valoare = 'eee' THEN 'eee' ELSE NULL END)
     , [7] = MAX(CASE WHEN Valoare = 'fff' THEN 'fff' ELSE NULL END)
     , [8] = MAX(CASE WHEN Valoare = 'ggg' THEN 'ggg' ELSE NULL END)
FROM   GEConfig
```

Comment: SAme answer as for Mark, I don't always know the value of Valoare field... I generate that value by this query  select   Valoare from GEConfig where Cimp in ('Societate','Adresa','Banca','CapitalSocial','Cont','CUI','NrRegCom','ModulReceptiiExtCotaTVA')

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * from
  (SELECT cast([name] AS nvarchar(MAX)) [name], row_number() over(
                                                                  ORDER BY name) AS id
   FROM TEMP)a pivot ( max([name])
                      FOR id IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5]) )pvt
```

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this using `COALESCE`:

```
declare @val varchar(max)

select @val = coalesce(@val, '') + ' ' + Valoare from GEConfig

select @val
```

Comment: This makes only one column, I want 8 columns.